# Dependency Injection clarification in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm having difficulty understanding DI, not really in relation to Angular 2 I think but just the design pattern. Reading through the docs here it starts with non-DI then shows how DI future proofs classes.

**No DI:**

```
public engine: Engine;
public tires: Tires;
public description = 'No DI';

constructor() {
  this.engine = new Engine();
  this.tires = new Tires();
}
```

---

What if the Engine class evolves and its constructor requires a parameter? That would break the Car class and it would stay broken until you rewrote it along the lines of this.engine = new Engine(theNewParameter). The Engine constructor parameters weren't even a consideration when you first wrote Car. You may not anticipate them even now. But you'll have to start caring because when the definition of Engine changes, the Car class must change. That makes Car brittle.

---

I understand that part.

**Docs have example with DI:**

```
public description = 'DI';

constructor(public engine: Engine, public tires: Tires) { }
```

---

Docs explain it's consumer's problem now, I understand that.

Wouldn't it be nice if you could simply list the things you want to build without having to define which dependency gets injected into what?

This is where the dependency injection framework comes into play. Imagine the framework had something called an injector. You register some classes with this injector, and it figures out how to create them.

When you need a Car, you simply ask the injector to get it for you and you're good to go.

---

Using Angular's DI what if the code in the injected service or the class changes. All the consumers have to be changed. What if there are a few consumer classes using the service and then the service changes one of it's functions, all consumers must update there code if they're using that function. Is the idea to just keep maintenance outside classes and in consumer code for the sake of separation of concerns? Please clarify and help me understand the dependency injection in Angular 2.

Comment: The get() function is not a function of a service. It's a method of the injector. The injector won't change. you ask the injector for a Car, and it gives you back a Car. get() doesn't, and won't take any additional parameter.

Comment: Why won't get take any additional parameters? Do you mean it shouldn't or it won't?

Comment: The injector is provided by the framework. Why would it introduce an additional parameter and break backward compatibility? To do what? Note that it's irrelevant anyway, since application code almost never use the injector. You use dependency injection, and the injector provides you the dependencies you need, simply by adding them as argument to the constructor.

Comment: ok I thought that was pseudo code which caused me some confusion.

Comment: If you quote text from another resource, please  provide the link reference.